# How to conclude a vector is space-like?

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, vectors, linear-algebra

I'm working with the Lorenztian inner product and would like to show that if a vector $v$ is lightlike, so $\langle v,v\rangle =0,$ and if $\langle v,w\rangle =0,$ then either $w$ is spacelike or $w$ is proportional to $v.$

So far I have that since $\langle v,v\rangle =0,$ then
$$v_0^2 = v_1^2 +v_2^2 +v_3^3$$
and
since $\langle v,w\rangle =0,$ then
$$v_0w_0 = v_1w_1 + v_2w_2 + v_3w_3.$$
I think I can then conclude that since
\begin{align*}
v_0v_0 &= v_1v_1 +v_2v_2 +v_3v_3, \\
v_0w_0 &= v_1w_1 + v_2w_2 + v_3w_3
\end{align*}
then $v_0=w_0,v_1=w_1, v_2=w_2, v_3=w_3.$
Does this mean that $v$ and $w$ are proportional? I'm not sure how to conclude that $w^a$ could be also be spacelike from the supposition.

Comment: What is the difference (if any) between $v$ and $v^a$?

Comment: There isn't a difference between $v$ and $v^a.$ I  just didn't use the index notation inside the inner product.

Comment: If there is no difference, I suggest you remove the unnecessary subscripts $^a$. It will be easier for the reader.

Comment: You cannot conclude that $v_0=w_0,v_1=w_1, v_2=w_2, v_3=w_3$ from the two equations above.  BTW, that would mean more than being proportional, it would mean being equal.

Comment: Hint: you can suppose that $v_2=v_3=0$ (by choosing an appropriate frame). Show then that $-w_0^2+w_1^2 = 0$, and conclude that $w$ is spacelike or lightlike.

Comment: @claude chuber : I think that you must post your comment as an answer.

Comment: If you understand any right answer to your question, don't be afraid to accept this as best upvoting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: you can suppose that $v_2=v_3=0$ (by choosing an appropriate frame). Show then that $−w_0^2+w_1^2=0$, and conclude that $w$ is spacelike or lightlike.

Comment: For $w$ to be spacelike, doesn't $-w_0^2 + w_1^2 >0?$ I thought that if it is equal to zero, then it is lightlike.

Comment: @Setsss  : 
$$
-w_0^2+w_1^2=0
\tag{01}
$$
$$
w_2^2+w_3^2\ge0
\tag{02}
$$
so
$$
-w_0^2+w_1^2+w_2^2+w_3^2\ge0
\tag{03}
$$